# How to move gameObject to a random object with specific tag

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out how to make an object move to the position of another object that has a specific tag. I currently have an object array that contains all of the "choices" the object has. Then I get a random number from 0 to the number of objects found. I tested this part and it seems to work well.

What I am stuck on is moving the object the script is on to the position of the object the script finds. What I think I need to do is to get the object associated with the index number and its position, but that isn't working. Thanks in advance! Sorry if this question isn't structured correctly, this is my first post!

```
public class objective : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject moveTo;
    public GameObject[] gameObjectChoices;
    public float choiceNumber;

    void Start()
    {
        //get objects with tag and apply it to object array
        gameObjectChoices = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("RandomCheesePoint");
        //choose one of the gameObjects in array
        choiceNumber = Random.Range(0, gameObjectChoices.Length);

        Debug.Log(choiceNumber);

        //move object to random object found
        transform.position = gameObjectChoices[choiceNumber].gameObject.transform.position;

        //problem occurs at gameObjectChoices[choiceNumber]
        //error message says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int' An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are attempting to index an array using a `float` value instead of an `int`.

`Random.Range()` will return an the same type as it's input parameters (in your case `int`) but this value is getting [implicitly cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) to a `float` because you declared your variable as:

```
public float choiceNumber;
```

If you change this to:

```
public int choiceNumber;
```

Then your code should work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! just like you said, it works perfectly.